# Position of each element of an array initializer

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-initialization

So I want to get the position of each of the element within the array initialiser for example:

```
 int [][][] testArray = new int [][][] {{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}};
```

how would i be able to get the position of each of the element within the part

```
 {{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}}
```

so for example:

```
testArray[0][0][0] gives -> the element 1
```

so how would i do this for any given arbitrary sized and arbitrary number of dimension array initialiser?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard with recursion. Why on earth do you need this?

Comment: by position you mean index?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I think what is required is (something like) a method with signature `int foo(Object arr, int... indices)` that takes a multidimensional int array (of unknown depth) and a sequence of indices and returns the position of the corresponding `int` in an array initialiser for `arr`. It's quite an interesting question, but the OP would need to pay me a fee before I'll write it!

Comment: @PaulBoddington Ok thanks for the explaination. Retracting the close-vote. Sure looks like a lot of "fun" :).

Comment: @PaulBoddington im building an obfuscator, and basically im blowing up the size of an array, however, you can also initalize an array like this, and once i blow up the size of the new array i then need to input the given data into the new array. im a student, could be you be nice to me? XD

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static Object sequential(Object o) {
    return sequential(o, new int[] {1});
}

private static Object sequential(Object o, int[] start) {
    if (o instanceof int[]) {
        int[] arr = (int[]) o;
        int length = arr.length;
        int[] copy = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            copy[i] = start[0]++;
        return copy;
    }
    Object[] arr = (Object[]) o;
    int length = arr.length;
    Object[] copy = arr.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        copy[i] = sequential(arr[i], start);
    return copy;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][][] array = {{{10, 9}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {}, {1}}};
    int[][][] positions = (int[][][]) sequential(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(positions));
}
```

This program outputs

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [], [14]]].
```

The method `sequential` converts any multidimensional `int` array (without `null`s) into an array of the same "shape" but with entries 1, 2, 3...
Therefore if you want to know the position of e.g. `array[1][1][3]` in an array initialiser for `array`, you can just do `positions[1][1][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider this String processing method:

```
static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "(\\{*).*?(\\}*)" );
static final String init= "{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}}";
static String unwrap( String s, int... index ){
    String inner = s.substring( 1, s.length()-1 );
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher( inner );
    if( mat.matches() ){
        String splitter = 
            "(?<=" + Pattern.quote( mat.group(2) ) +
            "),(?=" + Pattern.quote( mat.group(1) ) + ")";
        String[] elems = inner.split( splitter );
        if( index.length == 1 ){
            return elems[index[0]];
        } else {
            return unwrap( elems[index[0]], 
                           Arrays.copyOfRange( index, 1, index.length) );
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException( "Inconsistent data" );
}
```

The code is based on the observation that the initial `{{{...{` and the trailing `}}}...}` reflect the number of dimensions. One brace less is on either side "bracket" the comma, separating the elements of the outermost level. (Note that the -1 is neatly achieved by taking the substring from the first to next but last character.) Using the right amount of closing and opening braces as a look behind and a look ahead splits the initializer into the initializations of the outermost level. Use the first index from the array of indices to select the right one, and repeat with this sub-initializer and a reduced set of indices, or stop for the last index which must select the int element.

Comment: hi sorry could you just explain your code a bit not too sure about it?  or maybe its just late but could you explain a bit please ?

Comment: @AlanLiang I've added some explanations to my answer.